# If one moves after submitting an N-400 Application for Naturalization Form, can this cause the application to be transferred to another USCIS office?

Tags: usa, citizenship, paperwork

If one moves after submitting an N-400 Application for Naturalization Form, can this cause the application to be transferred to another USCIS field office?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://www.justia.com/immigration/naturalization-citizenship/moving-after-applying-for-citizenship/, the answer is yes, moving will likely cause the application to be transferred to another USCIS field office:

> Moving Before the Interview Is Scheduled.
>
> While USCIS is not required to schedule your interview in an office near your new location, USCIS likely will transfer your file to the office closest to your location once you change your address. You will get the notice of interview at your new address, and it will occur at the office in your area. Meanwhile, if you are planning to move before your interview would be scheduled, but you have not yet moved or changed your address, you can ask USCIS to schedule your interview at an office near your future location. This involves contacting that office to tell them about your projected move.
>
> Moving After the Interview Is Scheduled
>
> The first step in this situation is to notify USCIS about your new address. The office that previously scheduled your interview will cancel it and forward your file to the USCIS office near your new location. The new office will schedule the naturalization interview at a different date and time.
>
> If USCIS fails to take your change of address into account and does not cancel your original interview, you can still attend that interview. The USCIS office probably will host that interview without any problems, and then it will transfer your file to the office in your area. If you pass the interview, USCIS will schedule your naturalization ceremony at a location near your new home. In some cases, though, the USCIS office near your old address might refuse to conduct the interview. You might need to wait for your new address to enter the records and for USCIS to schedule a new interview.

Changing one's address may result in the application process getting postponed, according to https://gbricenolaw.com/contact/spokane-immigration-law/:

> There are specific actions you can take that will affect either your eligibility for certain statuses (including spending too long outside the U.S.) or delays in your application review process (e.g., if you change addresses after an application has been submitted).